# Use datatable for server side data

Tags: php, html, ajax

Am presently getting my data from a server side file and passing the result to my html using AJAX. Am doing this so that i can get new data without refreshing my page.

**Problem**
Datatable is not working on it as it does not recognize my server side result as data. instead it shows "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries". when i try to search it comes up empty

**HTML**

```
<table id='example1' class='table table-hover table-striped'>
         <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Stat</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Problem</th>
          <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody id='tab'>

           </tbody>
          <tfoot>
             <tr>
         <th>Stat</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Problem</th>
          <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
```

**AJAX**

```
function ajaxCall() {
$.ajax({
    url: "anfi.php", 
    success: (function (result) {
        $("#tab").html(result);
    })
})
};

ajaxCall(); // To output when the page loads
setInterval(ajaxCall, (5 * 1000)); // x * 1000 to get it in seconds


$(function () {
$("#example1").DataTable();
});
```

**PHP FILE**

```
echo"<tr>";

$notarray = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_desc('ticket','ticket_id');
        foreach($notarray as $row):
        $first = DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('firstname','user','user_id',$row['user_id']);
        $last = DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('lastname','user','user_id',$row['user_id']);
        $title = DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('name','ticket_title','ticket_title_id',$row['ticket_title']);
        $full = $first.' '.$last;
            echo"<td class='mailbox-star'><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-circle text-blue'></i></a></td>
            <td class='mailbox-name'><a href='ticket_details?ref=".$row['reference']."'>" . $full . "</a></td>
            <td class='mailbox-subject'><p class='carshow' title='".$title."- ". $row['subject'] . "'><b>" . $title . "</b>-" . $row['subject'] . "</p></td>
            <td class='mailbox-date'>" . $row['ticket_open_date'] . "</td>
          </tr>";
             endforeach;
     echo"</tr>";
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Comment: you missing echo $full;